# VueJs 2.6.11 + Vuetify - vdata-table - BUG?? - How do I keep width columns even when headers are hidden?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, v-data-table

I have the same problem but with Vuejs2 : [Vuetify v1.5 data table, how to determine column widths when the header is hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66226283/vuetify-v1-5-data-table-how-to-determine-column-widths-when-the-header-is-hidden)

Here is what I have:

```
<v-data-table 
:headers="headers" 
:items="items"
item-key="id"
hide-default-footer 
disable-pagination 
:hide-default-header="false"
>
```

For the headers:

```
headers: [
  { text: 'a', value: 'a', width: "4%" },
  { text: 'b', value: 'b', width: "4%" },
  { text: 'c', value: 'c', width: "7%" },
  { text: 'd', value: 'd', width: "10%" },
  { text: 'e', value: 'e', width: "8%" },
  { text: 'f', value: 'f', width: "13%" },
  { text: 'g', value: 'g', width: "10%" },
  { text: 'h', value: 'h', width: "13%" },
  { text: 'i', value: 'i', width: "31%" }
]
```

The sum of widths is 100% so no weird behavior should be expected.
When I set `:hide-default-header="true"` all the columns change the width.
How can I force the width of the column ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally used refs to access in my methods the DOM and modify it from the code.
It works but it's garbage code...